# calling shell_exec("php myscript.php") goes into infinite loop

Tags: php, bash, exec, shell-exec

I decided to fork out my php script because it takes too long to run. When I ran it shell_exec() call on a local linux machine, I did not see the infinite loop problem, but on a hosted machine, the script went into an infinite loop. I reduced the code to the minimum and I hope someone can help me see the problem here:

3 scripts are involved: 
**test_shell.php -->   issues shell_exec() to forkphp.sh --> which issues a command "path/to/php write_hello_world.php"**

starting from top to bottom order, first the test_shell.php script:

```
<?php
    if(function_exists('shell_exec')) {
            echo "shell_exec() is enabled";
    }

    $cmd = "./forkphp.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &";
    echo "<br/> About to shell_exec($cmd)<br/>";
    $out = shell_exec($cmd);
    echo $out;
```

?>

Here is forkphp.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# About to run /usr/bin/php  write_hello_world.php
echo $(/usr/bin/php write_hello_world.php)
```

Finally, here is write_hello_word.php :

```
<?php
$data = "This is a test : testing \n testing \n ";

file_put_contents ("deleteme.txt",$data);
```

?>

This gets an infinite loop where file 'deleteme.txt' continuously re-written . I am only guessing that I maybe misusing the '$' somewhere?
Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: What is the end purpose you are trying to serve here? On the face of there's no point in having the intermediate shell script, you might as well just call the child PHP process directly. However I still can't see a good reason for an infinite loop with this - but since the file will always have the same content at the end of this, how you *know* that this is what's happening?

Comment: @DaveRandom: "I decided to fork out my php script because it takes too long to run."

Comment: I tail the file with tail -f deleteme.txt and I see it the text streaming. as to the reason why I am doing through an intermediate file is because direct call from php file to shell_exec() another php file was not working for me, so this was a way around it

Comment: @GigaWatt There's still no reason to have the intermediate shell script though...

Comment: @seedhom: In `write_hello_world.php` add `microtime(1)` to the end of `$data`.  Check the file to see if it is actually being re-written or if it just appears to be.  Also, it might be worth checking the process tree on the box to see exactly what's launching what.

Comment: You do actually exec not fork

Comment: @seedhom: that's probably a visual bug with your SSH tool.  `file_put_contents` overwrites the file, so you shouldn't be seeing multiple lines from `tail`.

Comment: ps aux shows the forkphp.php process and the 'php write_hello_world.php' process gets a new PID every ps check

Comment: Thanks for your help, but just to clarify; I used the intermediate file because the original direct call from the first script to shell_exec("php write_hello_world &") was not working and I was wondering if my host provider is blocking php from using exec to initiate another php file, so I tried it this way. Again, on my local standalone linux machine this is working.

Comment: Here's a simple example of the problem: 
`<?php exec ("php -v"); `
Loops until it crashes
`<?php exec ("php -v >> log");`
Log shows the following over and over
`Running
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38
Content-type: text/html`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the [`FILE_APPEND`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) flag to `file_put_contents()`, otherwise the file would being overwritten again and again:

```
file_put_contents ("deleteme.txt",$data, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: making this change made the file "deleteme.txt" grow very fast!

Comment: Read something like this in the question already. Cannot really imagine with just seeing the code. Will make a test locally. Give me a couple of minutes.... However `FILE_APPEND` is required in any case

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Can it be that your real code isn't as simple as the code you've posted?

Comment: Btw, what are you expecting from the `echo` : `echo $(/usr/bin/php write_hello_world.php)` ? `write_hello_world.php` won't output anything

Comment: True. echo was just leftover from my experimentation. No purpose.

Comment: hek2mgl, as to the simplicity of the code, I only changed the php file names. I believe and hope I maintained the call sequence accurately.  I have a stronger belief now that my hosting provided has done something to shell_exec() when that is not default behavior.