# Running PHP Files Through Shell_Exec

Tags: php, command-line-interface, shell-exec

I want to be able to execute command line php through shell_exec, but I always get an infinite loop.

```
<? shell_exec('php -v');
```

Begins a loop. Running it with file output lets me see the result

```
<? shell_exec('php -v >> log');
```

log shows the following repeated

```
Running
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38
Content-type: text/html
```

Other commands work fine. For instance, the following logs a directory listing.

```
<? shell_exec('ls > log')
```

Launching a bash file which subsequently launches a php command does the same loop. Launching a php file which just says "Hello World" loops as well.

```
<? shell_exec('helloworld.php')
```

The same error occurs with one > or two >> as well as with other similar commands like  `passthru('php -v')` or `exec('php -v')`

This similar question was never solved: [calling shell_exec(“php myscript.php”) goes into infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150958/calling-shell-execphp-myscript-php-goes-into-infinite-loop)

Comment: `php -v` should just display the PHP version, it shouldn't start a loop or display HTTP headers.

Comment: Maybe `php` uses environment variables to detect if it's running from the CLI or the webserver. And when you run it using `shell_exec()` from a web script, it inherits the environment variables and thinks it's being run by the server.

Comment: @Barmar, exactly. I want it to show the php version in this example. Any idea of a workaround if environmental variables are the case?

Comment: same here, this line triggered an infinite recursive call on one of our user (hosted by 1and1): https://github.com/Combodo/iTop/blob/a86079c477794cb344d883c44725d944f2a6f308/datamodels/2.x/itop-config/src/Validator/iTopConfigSyntaxValidator.php#L20